# How to disable boot animation in android (Lineage OS) without root?

Tags: android, operating-system, lineageos

I have lineage os installed in my android device I want to disable boot animation how to do it?

Comment: Did you tried these steps? https://www.technologyhint.com/disable-boot-animation-android/

Comment: My device is not rooted :(.. is it possible to disable boot animation if my device is not rooted?